# how to keep aspect ratio while resizing in css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to keep the aspect ratio while resizing div like this:

```css
.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  height: 20rem;
  width: 20rem;
  min-height: 10rem;
  min-width: 10rem;
  background-color:green;
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}
    
.item_img {
  
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/NYCtjSn/unknown.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="item_img" draggable="false"></div>
</div>
```

but I'm trying to replace the image with pure css instead of having to keep a link to load image:

```css
.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
  height: 20rem;
  width:20rem;
  min-height: 10rem;
  min-width: 10rem;
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;

}
    
.item_img {
  position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.unknown_icon {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.unknown_icon::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 35%;
  width:35%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 30%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: white;
}

.unknown_icon::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 80%;
  width: 80%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="item_img unknown_icon"></div>
</div>
```

But when you resize this one it does not keep the aspect ratio like in the previous one with the image
[image]

How do I solve this problem? perhaps with [`aspect-ratio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio)?

Answer (score 0):

try

```css
.item_img {
  position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: nope still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Use `aspect-ratio`. Although it be irregular after resizing:

```css
.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
  height: 20rem;
  width: 20rem;
  min-height: 10rem;
  min-width: 10rem;
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item_img {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.unknown_icon {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.unknown_icon::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1; /* here */
  width: 35%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 30%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: white;
}

.unknown_icon::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1; /* here */
  width: 80%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="item_img unknown_icon"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: nope it looks really disoriented after resizing